# How to build the file using MSBuild

Tags: c#, batch-file, msbuild

I created a C# file. Normally we build it using the Visual Studio IDE. But I want to build it using MSBuild.

I have one `.bat` and `.xml` file. What exactly I have to do with `.xml` file to build that `.cs` file successfully?

My `.xml` file:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="tools.dir" location="${env.TOOLS_DIR}"/>

<target name="Buildproject" >
<echo message="I am building project"/>
</target>   

<target name="runtests" depends="Buildproject" description="This is my first ant target">
<echo message="Running tests"/>
</target>

<target name="publish" depends="runtests">
<echo message="Publish artifact"/>
</target>
```

My `.bat` file

> SET WORKSPACE=%~dp0 SET TOOLS_DIR=buildtools SET
> BUILD_FILE=sample_build.xml @echo off echo WORKSPACE: %WORKSPACE% echo
> TOOLS_DIR: %TOOLS_DIR% echo BUILD_FILE: %BUILD_FILE%
> %TOOLS_DIR%/apache-ant/bin/ant -Divy.cache.ttl.default=eternal
> -buildfile %BUILD_FILE%

Comment: This XML file is not a build file. It does not contain any information about the project or how it is to be built. If you had a suitable MSBuild file, you would just run `msbuild.exe` and specify it as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is not right.  It looks like maybe a nant file or some other specification.

Here is your most basic .proj (msbuild definition) file.

Save this (in the same directory as your .sln file) as "MyMsbuildDef.proj"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">
        <CallTarget Targets="BuildItUp" />
    </Target>


    <Target Name="BuildItUp" >
        <MSBuild Projects="$(WorkingCheckout)\MySolution_Or_MyProject_File.sln" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
            <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TargetOutputsItemName"/>
        </MSBuild>
        <Message Text="BuildItUp completed" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Obviously, change "MySolution_Or_MyProject_File.sln" to your .sln name.

Now create a .bat file called "MyMsbuildCallIt.bat" and put this in:

```
REM set __msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
REM set __msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
set __msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

call "%__msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" /target:AllTargetsWrapped "MyMsbuildDef.proj" /p:Configuration=Debug;FavoriteFood=Popeyes /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyMsbuildDef_Debug.log
call "%__msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" /target:AllTargetsWrapped "MyMsbuildDef.proj" /p:Configuration=Release;FavoriteFood=Popeyes /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyMsbuildDef_Release.log


set __msBuildDir=
```

And run the .bat file.

That is your most basic msbuild scenario.